# How to integrate Elasticsearch in Zend Framework 2 using Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch, zend-framework2, elastica

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/) for integrating doctrine with Zend Framework 2. Now, all is working fine, but I would like to integrate Elasticsearch to this project.

I found a lot of documentation about Elasticsearch, I downloaded the Elastica plugin for PHP, but I don't know where to get started.

I searched tutorials to integrate Elasticsearch with Doctrine, but they're all about Symfony.
Could someone please explain me (in a simple way) how to use ElasticSearch in Zend Framework 2, using Doctrine 2 as ORM to index and search through my objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are no direct relation exists between **Doctrine 2** and **Elasticsearch**. While primary concern of Doctrine ORM is persisting, updating and reading data on relational databases, elasticsearch mainly focuses on indexing and searching that data. Instead of thinking about *"integrating elasticsearch with doctrine"*, think about *"how can i use both doctrine and elasticsearch in same application"*.

Whenever you create or update a record in database, you would probably want to do more operations like indexing that data on *Elasticsearch* or *Solr*, caching or invalidating already cached version of same data on **Memcached** or **Redis** etc.. To do that properly (or zf2 way), you should carefully design a service layer which [orchestrates](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) both persistency operations and related post-processes like indexing on elasticsearch, caching, cache invalidating, logging etc..

Accomplishing some of these operations by firing some events via [EventManager](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) would be an appropriate decision.

> Note: Don't utilize EventManager heavily for simple & straightforward tasks such as writing a log line. Events are not free, especially in ZF2. (*Quite improved in ZF3, but still not free*).

---

For question, here is the way to go with Zend Framework 2 while utilizing a 3rd party library which is [ruflin/elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica):

**A.** Open your terminal and type

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ php composer.phar selfupdate
$ php composer.phar require ruflin/elastica:dev-master
```

**B.** Create a factory for elastica client `Application\Service\ElasticaClientFactory.php`

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ElasticaClientFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $config = $sl->get('Config');
        $clientOptions = isset($config['elastica']) ? $config['elastica'] : array();
        $client = new \Elastica\Client($clientOptions);

        return $client;
    }
}
```

**C.** Add elastica configuration and register new factory class to service locator in your `module.config.php`:

```
'elastica' => array(
    'servers' => array(
        array('host' => '127.0.0.1','port' => 9200),
        // You can add more servers when necessary
        // array('host' => '127.0.0.1','port' => 9200)
        ),
    ),

service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'elastica-client' => 'Application\Service\ElasticaClientFactory'
    ),
)
```

At this point, in any controller (bad) or service (good) you can grab the elastica client instance like this:

```
$elastica = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('elastica-client');
```

## Bonus: Using Service Initializers and Traits

If your PHP version is ≥ 5.4 you can use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) while automatically injecting the Elastica Client into your services with the help of [service initializers](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.html#initializers).

**D.** Create a new interface named `Application\Service\ElasticaAwareInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

interface ElasticaAwareInterface
{
    public function getElasticaClient();
    public function setElasticaClient(\Elastica\Client $client);
}
```

**E.** Create a new trait named `Application\Traits\ElasticaAwareTrait.php` (Notice the path. Create the *Traits* folders if doesn't exists)

```
<?php
namespace Application\Traits;

trait ElasticaAwareTrait
{
    protected $client = null;

    public function getElasticaClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setElasticaClient(\Elastica\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**F.** Create a new initializer named `Application\Initializers\ElasticaInitializer.php` (Notice the path, again)

```
<?php
namespace Application\Initializers;

use Zend\ServiceManager\InitializerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Service\ElasticaAwareInterface;

class ElasticaInitializer implements InitializerInterface
{
    /**
     * Initializer for the elastica-aware domain services.
     * Properly creates a new elastica client and injects it into related service.
     */
    public function initialize($service, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        /**
         * Beware: This if statement will be run for every service instance
         * we grab from $serviceManager because the nature of initializers.
         * This worth think about on it. With ZF3 this went further. 
         * We may load our services lazily using delegator factories.
         */ 
        if ($service instanceof ElasticaAwareInterface) {
            $service->setElasticaClient( $serviceManager->get('elastica-client') );
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now, we can put together all parts. Say, we have a service named `UserService` which uses a Doctrine entity manger (or UserRepository better), also needs to use **Elastica**.

**G.** Register our service to service manager:

```
service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'elastica-client' => 'Application\Service\ElasticaClientFactory'
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'user-service' => 'Application\Service\UserService'
    )
)
```

Finally, the `UserService` signature:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

use Application\Service\ElasticaAwareInterface;

class UserService implements ElasticaAwareInterface
{
    // Here is our trait
    use \Application\Traits\ElasticaAwareTrait;

    public function fooMethod()
    {
        // Do some things with doctrine EM here..

        // And grab the elastica client easily anywhere in UserService
        $client = $this->getElasticaClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer! bonus - traits! yeah!

Comment: You answer is very detailed and look simple to understan for a beginner like me, i'll test it tomorow (it's late in my country) and give you feedback. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi, so i tried you solution, but i get this error when i'm calling $elastica = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('elastica-client'); :

While attempting to create elasticaclient(alias: elastica-client) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.

Comment: can you create a gist on gist.github.com for your current module.config.php and ElasticaServiceFactory.php contents?

Comment: Of course i can, here it is :
https://gist.github.com/Argurth/fce3aeb8a1c2f93abc79

Comment: Ah it seems ok except one. can you try with `$sl->get('Config')` instead of `$sl->get('Configuration')` in factory? I also updated the answer.

Comment: I'll make it this afternoon and give you feedback !

Comment: I get it working, it was because of wrong directory for the service one. Thanks !
After that, to use it, i must indexate user when i add them, is that right ?

Comment: All work greatly ^^ what did you mean by "integrate EventManager" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some (still under heavy development) modules out there that combine Doctrine2 and ElasticSearch. For example check out [this module called `OcraElasticSearch`](https://github.com/Ocramius/OcraElasticSearch) from the Doctrine2+ZF2 Master @Ocramius himself :)

Otherwise it seems that Symfony2 is a step ahead when it comes to integrating Doctrine and ElasticSearch.

I bet within one or two months you should be able to find more alternatives on GitHub.

Since we need similar functionality soon I might discover more later. If I do I will update my post.